# Child field event handling issue in custom HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, event-handling

I am trying to create a customized list field where, I have more then 2 clickable buttons in each row. For that i have customized the HorizontalFieldManager and created own manager to align the field elements. Now UI is perfectly fine.

**But, I am struggling to handle the events work for both.**

**Step-1** I have used fieldChangedListener for buttons added in row. It is working fine

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {}
```

**step-2**  have used navigation click to handle event on the parent manager.

```
  protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            Field field = getFieldWithFocus();
            Dialog.alert("shops field clicked");        
                return super.navigationClick(status, time);
        }
```

Now, even the navigationClick event works. But as the button is the child field added to VFM. When i click on the button both the VFM and button event comes together.

How could i restrict only to the button while it is clicked on the ButtonField.

Comment: Try applying `ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK` style on the buttons.

Comment: Did my answer answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the `navigationClick()` to be called only  for the child field (clickable button) without being called for the manager. Sorry to disappoint you, but you can't.The navigation click event will always be called first for the manager and only than the manager will propagate the event to the child field. The same hold for keys events, touch events, focus events and etc...

Describe what you are trying to achieve, add a code snippet and I am sure we will find a solution.